# Insert into InfluxDB

Tags: database, insert, influxdb

I am trying to insert the following into InfluxDB

```
INSERT L,entity_id=water_meter_mains litres=27 1596240000
```

but I am getting an error: unable to parse invalid boolean.
L, water_meter_mains and litres do not exist in my database .. maybe I need to create a table or measurement before? I have some experience with SQL but InfluxDB is totally a new concept for me.

Answer (score 0):

my database required nanosecond-precision Unix time .. the following worked:

```
L,entity_id=water_meter_mains value=27 1596240000000000000
```